# python program to convert mapper and reducer program for hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop

I have two programs that the first program is about to convert .h5 file to .tiff file and second program is predict temperature using arima model.

here is first program for converting .h5 file to .tiff file and min and max .tiff and it also call geo tiff.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import os
import h5py
from collections import defaultdict
from osgeo import osr
import datetime

in_dir = r'/Users/sunnybhargav/Desktop/jan'
out_dir = r'/Users/sunnybhargav/Desktop/new_output'
#in_dir = input('Enter input directory path where hdf files are stored: ')
#out_dir = input('Enter output directory path where geotiff files are to be stored: ') 



def arrayToTif(array,tifFilePath,proj,transform,nodatavalue):
 with open(tifFilePath,'a') as file:

    pass

# write raster
out_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(tifFilePath,
                                              array.shape[1],
                                              array.shape[0],
                                              1,  #Number of bands
                                              gdal.GDT_Float32)

out_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array)
out_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(nodatavalue)

# close tif to write into disk (free tif file) 
out_ds = None 



dates_dict = defaultdict(list)

for root,directories,filenames in os.walk(in_dir):
    for filename in filenames:
       if (filename.endswith('.h5')):

            hdffileDate = filename[6:15]
            hdfdate = (int(hdffileDate[0:2]))
            dates_dict[hdfdate].append(filename)
            print(filename)

 for key in dates_dict.keys():

  file_list = dates_dict[key]
  min_lst = 1000*np.ones((2816,2805))
  max_lst = -1000*np.ones((2816,2805))

for v in file_list:

    hdf_ds = h5py.File(os.path.join(in_dir,v))
    lst = np.array(hdf_ds['LST'])[0,:,:]


    hdf_ds = gdal.Open(os.path.join(in_dir,v))
    metadata = hdf_ds.GetMetadata_Dict()

    lst = lst.astype('Float32')
    max_lst = np.maximum(max_lst,lst)

    lst[lst==-999] = 999
    min_lst = np.minimum(min_lst,lst)





   min_lst[min_lst==999] = -999
   transform = (0,1,0,0,0,-1)
   proj = None
   nodatavalue = -999

   tiffileDate = v[6:15]
   MinName = 'MIN' +v[0:2]+str.lower(tiffileDate) + '.tif'
   MaxName = 'MAX' +v[0:2]+str.lower(tiffileDate) + '.tif'


arrayToTif
(max_lst,os.path.join(out_dir,MaxName),proj,transform,nodatavalue)



arrayToTif
(min_lst,os.path.join(out_dir,MinName),proj,transform,nodatavalue)


del lst
del min_lst
del max_lst
```

second program

in second program is for tiff to get ndarray and then get out put for particular all max temprature and predict next 5 day prediction.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib 
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from numpy import genfromtxt
import csv
import datetime
from datetime import datetime 
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas import Series
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import numpy
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf, pacf
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np 
import subprocess
import gdal,osr
from gdalconst import *
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import scipy.misc
from datetime import datetime

# import timeseries as ts 
count = 1
max_temp = []
min_temp = []
filename = []
filenamer = []
max_temp_points = []
min_temp_points = []
source = r'/Volumes/bhargav 1/data/NEW_MAX'

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(source):
  print(filenames)
  for f in filenames:

    print (f)
    dataset = gdal.Open( source + '//' + f  ,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    #print(dataset)
    geotransform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
    band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
    data = band.ReadAsArray(0,0,dataset.RasterXSize,dataset.RasterYSize).astype(np.float64)
    #print(np.histogram(data,bins=500))
    print(np.shape(data))
    max_temp_point = data[793][1160] 
    max_temp_point = max_temp_point - 273
    print(max_temp_point)
    print("Count:",count)
    max_temp_points.append(max_temp_point)
    count = count + 1
print(np.shape(max_temp_points))
print(np.mean(max_temp_points))
count = 1
np.save("Max_temp_points_1",max_temp_points)

X = max_temp_points

model = ARIMA(X, order=(5,0,4))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=-1)
# print summary of fit model
print(model_fit.summary())
forecast = model_fit.predict()
print (forecast)


# plot
start_index = len(X)
end_index = start_index + 6
predict_val = model_fit.predict(start=start_index, end=end_index)
print('Prediction:',predict_val)


pyplot.plot(X)

pyplot.plot(forecast, color='red')
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: And whats your question?

Comment: Well, if you wanted to use Hadoop, 1) `/Users` or `/Volumes` can't be used. 2) You must install every single numpy, scipy, PIL, etc. dependency on every single Hadoop server in the cluster. Obviously won't scale well in a large cluster. 3) You can't just import Hadoop libraries and change a few lines and expect this to work... For example, Hadoop Streaming reads files line by line, not entire files at once http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

Comment: I want this code to run in Hadoop. It is /Users is a path to that file for in put.